# Custom command to lay out a row of images

Tags: macros, graphics, expl3

I'm learning `expl3`, and to practice I created a simple command to lay out a row of images so that the row fits in one line and all the images have the same height and, optionally, a spacing between them.

The code, however, doesn't produce what I'd expect:

[image]

see the extra white space after the last rule (I replace the `\skip_horizontal:N` with a `\rule` to improve visibility). If I set the optional spacing to `0pt`, however, it works, so I assume my mistake is in the spacing between the figures. But I couldn't figure out where the problem is.

The code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\LinhaDeFiguras
  { O{\textwidth}
    D(){0pt}
    m }
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #3 }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { - #2 }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
      {
        \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box
          { \includegraphics [height=1cm] { ##1 } }
        \dim_add:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { #2 + \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
      }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { 1cm * \dim_ratio:nn { #1 } { \l_tmpa_dim } }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
      {
        \includegraphics [height=\l_tmpa_dim] { ##1 }
        \rule { #2 } { #2 }
        % \skip_horizontal:N #2 \scan_stop:
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\LinhaDeFiguras(5pt){
  example-image-16x10,
  example-image-10x16,
  example-image,
  example-image-16x9,
  example-image-9x16,
  example-image-golden,
  }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is good, but I'd subtract the necessary number of spaces from the stated width and compute the final height from this. The spaces can be inserted between the images at the end.

I'd also allocate specific variables for the task.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\LinhaDeFiguras { O{\textwidth} D(){0pt} m }
  {
    \latexer_lf_main:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  }

\dim_new:N \l_latexer_lf_width_dim
\dim_new:N \l_latexer_lf_height_dim
\dim_new:N \l_latexer_lf_sofar_dim
\seq_new:N \l_latexer_lf_items_seq
\seq_new:N \l_latexer_lf_output_seq
\box_new:N \l_latexer_lf_figure_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \latexer_lf_main:nnn
  {
    \dim_zero:N \l_latexer_lf_sofar_dim
    \seq_clear:N \l_latexer_lf_output_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_latexer_lf_items_seq { #3 }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_latexer_lf_width_dim
      { #1 - #2 * (\seq_count:N \l_latexer_lf_items_seq - 1) }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_latexer_lf_items_seq
      {
        \hbox_set:Nn \l_latexer_lf_figure_box
          { \__latexer_lf_image:nn { 1cm } { ##1 } }
        \dim_add:Nn \l_latexer_lf_sofar_dim
          { \box_wd:N \l_latexer_lf_figure_box }
      }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_latexer_lf_height_dim
      { 1cm * \dim_ratio:nn { \l_latexer_lf_width_dim } { \l_latexer_lf_sofar_dim } }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_latexer_lf_items_seq
      {
       \seq_put_right:Nn \l_latexer_lf_output_seq
         { \__latexer_lf_image:nn { \l_latexer_lf_height_dim } { ##1 } }
      }
    \seq_use:Nn \l_latexer_lf_output_seq
      {
        % \rule { #2 } { #2 } % for debugging
        \skip_horizontal:n { #2 }
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__latexer_lf_image:nn
  {
    \includegraphics[height=#1]{#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\LinhaDeFiguras(5pt){
  example-image-16x10,
  example-image-10x16,
  example-image,
  example-image-16x9,
  example-image-9x16,
  example-image-golden,
  }

\bigskip

\noindent
\LinhaDeFiguras[8cm](20pt){
  example-image-16x10,
  example-image-10x16,
  example-image,
  example-image-16x9,
  example-image-9x16,
  example-image-golden,
  }

\end{document}
```

[image]